# Flutter firebase data model

Tags: flutter

```
class AllRideRequest {
  String? name;
  String? destinationAddress;
   DriverLocation? driverLocation;
  AllRideRequest({
    this.name,
    this.destinationAddress, this.driverLocation
  });
  AllRideRequest.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    name = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["userName"];
    destinationAddress = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["destinationAddress"];
    driverLocation = DriverLocation.fromSnapshot(dataSnapshot);
  }
}

class DriverLocation {
  double? latitude;
  double? longitude;
  DriverLocation({
    this.latitude,
    this.longitude,
  });
  DriverLocation.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    latitude = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["latitude"];
    longitude = (dataSnapshot.value as Map)["longitude"];
  }
}
```

i have a data model like this. Name and destinationAddress has a value but DriverLocation lat long null how can i fix this problem

i want to reach this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsoOF.png

Comment: What you want to fix ?, Please give some more info, Like checking the null value or handle the null value ?

Comment: latitude and longitude has value in firebase but comes null is it my data model wrong

Comment: Send the screenshot or check, whether you using the correct  key word (Same as firebase one) "latitude" and "longitude" .

Comment: Also send the Code where you, fetching the "latitude" and "longitude"

Comment: I added a photo

Comment: I can use name and destination Address but not working for latitude and longitude

Comment: Not able see the data flow hierarchy,  At-least send your JSON.

Comment: i dont have a json

Comment: Not send complete image and don't know the json, Then how can i help you my friend.

Comment: I'm just asking how to use a data model in the map structure created in firebase. others are working

Comment: What is the Data structure (Collection, Doc, fields ) ?

Comment: {
    "userName": "userName",
    "destinationAddress": "destinationAddress",
    "driverLocation": {
        "latitude": "342342343",
        "longitude": "22343423"
    }
}

Comment: Is this you model ?

Comment: no data structure can you please review the picture i am wondering how can i create a model of it

Comment: I don't have a json because I'm using firebase, but we can think of it like this

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
class ResponseData {

String? userName;
  String? destinationAddress;
  DriverLocation? driverLocation;

  ResponseData({this.userName, this.destinationAddress, this.driverLocation});

  ResponseData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userName = json['userName'];
    destinationAddress = json['destinationAddress'];
    driverLocation = json['driverLocation'] != null
        ? new DriverLocation.fromJson(json['driverLocation'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userName'] = this.userName;
    data['destinationAddress'] = this.destinationAddress;
    if (this.driverLocation != null) {
      data['driverLocation'] = this.driverLocation!.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class DriverLocation {
  String? latitude;
  String? longitude;

  DriverLocation({this.latitude, this.longitude});

  DriverLocation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    latitude = json['latitude'];
    longitude = json['longitude'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['latitude'] = this.latitude;
    data['longitude'] = this.longitude;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: ``` FirebaseDatabase.instance
              .ref()
              .child("All Ride Requests")
              .child(allRideRequestKeys[i])
              .once()
              .then((snap) {
            if (snap.snapshot.value != null) {
              var myOrders = AllRideRequest.fromSnapshot(snap.snapshot);
              Provider.of<AppInfo>(context, listen: false)
                  .updateOverAllMyOrdersHistoryInformation(myOrders);``` I'm trying to do it as you posted, but this time I get an error in the part that says fromsnapshot, how can I fix it?